# SmallCheck: check infinity of the set of Ints

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

The set of integers is infinite, so for any `n <- Z` there is some `m > n`, and I try to show it with SmallCheck test:

```
...

    , testProperty "infinity of integers set" $
      forAll $ \(n::Integer) -> exists $ \m -> m > n

...
```

It fails with:

```
...

  infinity of Ints:              FAIL
    there exists 5 such that
      argument does not exist
    Use -p '/infinity of Ints/' to rerun this test only.

...
```

I tried to swap `for-all` quantification prefix with `existence` prefix: the result is the same - fail. My intuition is that it's because both quantified expressions use the same depth, so it's something like to try to prove that there is `k` in `n..m` that is greater than `m` -- is this the problem? Then how to modify the test to avoid it? I could try `localOption` function to change the depth for the `exists` part only (if this is the reason) but this function requires `TestTree` as an argument, `exists $ ...` is not `TestTree`

(but it's `exists :: forall (m :: Type -> Type) a. Testable m a => a -> Property m`)

Comment: That's frankly a bad property to check. You're not really investigating anything about the `Integer` type or its `>` operator here, but rather just properties of the smallcheck generator. And as you've guessed yourself: if `n` is already at the end of the range it checks (IOW: at the edge of the test distribution's support), then you won't find any that's higher yet. Even in QuickCheck I would not check such a property: it would _in principle_ work there (because QuickCheck supports smoothly decaying distributions), but inefficiently (when `n` is already big, it takes many tries to find `m`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the depth can be changed locally for a property with `changeDepth`:

```
    , testProperty "infinity of Ints" $
      forAll $ \(a::Integer) -> changeDepth (+1) $ exists $ \b -> b > a
```